# Keep getting Error: Cannot find module '@google-cloud/bigquery' in my Firebase cloud function even after installing it through npm

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-bigquery

I keep getting an error when i call my firebase cloud function, when i checked the logs on firebase console it says

```
Error: Cannot find module '@google-cloud/bigquery'
```

I installed it  using

```
npm install @google-cloud/bigquery
```

but I'm still getting the error

this is my package.json for reference

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "14"
  },
  "hosting": {
   
    "rewrites": [ {
      "source": "**",
      "function": "api"
    } ]
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^9.8.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.14.1" 
     

  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

could someone please help me resolve this, i have been stuck on it for days

this is my cloud function index.js for reference

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors')({ origin: true });
const { BigQuery } = require('@google-cloud/bigquery');
 
const bigquery = new BigQuery();

const app = express();
app.use(cors);
app.use(express.json());



exports.api = functions.https.onRequest(app);


app.post('/create_table', (req, res) => {
```

Comment: Are you sure you installed it in the `/functions` directory (I can't see it in `package.json`)? and not in Firebase project's root directory? Also try `npm ci` to perform clean install.

Comment: Please don't ask twice the same question.